# How to track behavior of ngModel array item using .directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, watch, angular-ngmodel

Hi everyone I'm use angularjs not so long time ago and now I have one issue related with this framework that i can't to solve. So the problem in next: I have few input fields that generate via ng-repeat:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(i, name) in name_list track by $index">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.name_list[i]" add-input/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where name_list some array with data. As result I have generated input fields. Next that i wanted to do it's adding new input field if all previously fields was $dirty for this thing i wrote next angular code:

```
userApp.directive('addInput', ['$compile', '$sce', function ($compile, $sce) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

       scope.inputCounter = scope.name_list.length;

       scope.$watch(
           function(){
                 return ngModel.$dirty
           },

           function(dirty_val){
               if (dirty_val){

               scope.name_list.push(ngModel.$modelValue);
               }
           }
       );
    }
}}]);
```

but of course this code works wrong (it add new field if at last one field is $dirty) I know why it works wrong but I do not know how to track all ng-models separate, I don't know how to get access to some model like ngModel[1],so I hope somebody will help me in this, thank's

Comment: This is quite weird. You probably want something else to be aware of all the inputs and decide to add a new input, rather than place this directive on each and every input. If we knew what you tried to do perhaps we could offer a better design.

Comment: i just want to add new input if all previously inputs are filled in (by default are 5 inputs are already placed on a page but if all of them are used automatically adding new input and if new input filled in adding one more input and etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a parent directive which will collect the dirty elements, and will add new element once it detects all of the other elements are dirty:

Check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sEZtsHATOeQEn21LpdyZ?p=preview).

HTML:

```
<div collect-input>
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(i, name) in name_list track by $index">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.name_list[i]" add-input/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once addInput detects it is dirty, call parent directive controller:

```
if (dirty)
    collectInput.reportInput();
```

JS:

```
directive('collectInput', function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: function($scope) {
    var dirtyCount = 0;
    this.reportInput = function() {
      var count = $scope.name_list.length;
      dirtyCount++;
      if (count === dirtyCount) {
        $scope.name_list.push('aaa');
      }
    }
  },
  }
}).
directive('addInput', ['$compile', '$sce', function ($compile, $sce) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: ['^collectInput', '?ngModel'],

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
       var collectInput = ctrls[0]
       var ngModel = ctrls[1];
       scope.inputCounter = scope.name_list.length;

       scope.$watch(
           function(){


     return ngModel.$dirty
       },

       function(dirty_val){
           if (dirty_val){
             collectInput.reportInput();
           }
       }
   );
}
}}]);
```